# Why am I getting an unboundLocalError?

Tags: python, local

Error I am getting is:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment?

Code:

```
def menu_option(index, count):
        import random
        random_number1 = random.randrange(1,31)
        random_number2 = random.randrange(1,31)
        if index == 1:
           problem = random_number1 + random_number2
        elif index == 2:
             problem = random_number1 - random_number2
        elif index == 3:
             problem = random_number1 * random_number2
        elif index == 4:
             problem = random_number1 // random_number2
        elif index == 5:
             problem = random_number1 % random_number2
        user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)
        return check_solution(user_solution, solution, count)
```

Comment: Please indent the code, it makes us easier to answer.

Comment: Which line its giving error on?

Comment: The error message is a bit bigger than that... it includes the line where the error happened. Can you post the entire error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chain of `if/elif/elif ...` suppose none of those conditions are met? Then `problem` is not assigned. But you try to use it in `user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)`. Looks like `problem` is the problem. The solution depends on what your design says should happen in this case. Is there a default that should be used? Raise your own exception? Return an error code? You have to decide that.

Answer (score 0):

In last line `return check_solution(user_solution, solution, count)` `solution` variable is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Like Himanshu said It is because you have used a variable `solution` to which you haven't done any assignment. So in this case python looks for it inside function if not, it will look for it in global. if it doesn't find any assignment to it before being used it raises `UnboundLocalError`, also the variable `problem` is confined to if block so i think it is not accessible outside. So assign `problem` with some value before nested if block and also check `solution` variable about what should be assigned before passing it in function.